# Office Scripts - Deleting rows of a table: The argument is invalid, is missing or has an invalid format

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, office-scripts

When trying to delete all the rows (except the first row) of all the tables of 'MySheet'

```js
    function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
      let sheet = workbook.getWorksheet('MySheet');
      let tables = sheet.getTables();
      let rowCount = 0;
    
      tables.forEach((table) => {
        rowCount = table.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getRowCount();
        table.deleteRowsAt(1, rowCount);
      });
    }
```

The script works well on the 1st table, but when looping through the second one, I get the error:

```
Line 8: Table deleteRowsAt: The argument is invalid, is missing or has an invalid format.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to delete the number of rows in the table but excluding the first one. So the error is because you're trying to delete one more row than is included in the table. Since you're excluding the first row, you have to subtract one from the rowCount to get it to delete correctly. You can see the updated code below. I added `-1` after rowCount on the `table.deleteRowsAt()` line:

```js
    function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
      let sheet = workbook.getWorksheet('MySheet');
      let tables = sheet.getTables();
      let rowCount = 0;
    
      tables.forEach((table) => {
        rowCount = table.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getRowCount();
        table.deleteRowsAt(1, rowCount-1);
      });
    }
```